# Not able move checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code for menulist item to toggle ,and add selected checkboxes to `div select2`. My issue is that when i add div element to parent category `<div>Programmer</div>` i am not able to add checked  items to `div select2`, how to correct this line

`return !$('#choose li :checked').closest('li').appendTo('#select2');`

so that this thing work?

```
<div class="left">
<ul id="accordion">
    <li><div>Programmer</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup" value="checkbox" id="1,1" />PHP</label>
            </li>
            <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="1,2" />.net</label>
            </li>
            <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="1,3" />JSP</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li id="2" class="accordion-toggle"><div>Event Manager</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup" value="checkbox" id="2,1" />Wedding</label>
            </li>
            <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="2,2" />Birthday</label>
            </li>
            <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="2,3" />Fairwell</label>
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </li>      
</ul>
</div>
<a href="#" id="add"/>add</a>
<a href="#" id="remove"/>remove</a>
<div class="right">
<ul id="select2">

</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#accordion > li > div").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion ul:eq(0)').show();
    $('#add').click(function() {
    return !$('#choose li :checked').closest('li').appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    return !$('#select2 li :checked').closest('li').appendTo('#select1');
});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add this code to jsfiddle ?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be more appreciated!

Comment: also question ain't clear

Comment: I tried to add in jsfiddle , but it doesn't works as work in my code , i am new to jsfiddle, `http://jsfiddle.net/e0mpspbd/` here i tried

Comment: where is `choose` I could not find it ??

Comment: @ozil You are right That was the mistake ,i changed it to `accordian` its working now